# JvListView - How to run code only when user clicks on checkbox?

Tags: delphi

I'm using improved (reportedly) version of ListView from Jedi pack. Unfortunately there is still no OnCheckboxClick event (!?). Is there any way to emulate this?

Comment: What version of Delphi you're using? Maybe you'd want to use an improved version of Delphi: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView.OnItemChecked . Should be available since XE2.

Comment: Delphi 7 + Jedi components ( http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/ )

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used this (Which was years ago) I believe that I just Had to use the checked[selitem] in the ordinary OnClick Event. I remember it being pretty straight-forward to use.

I've just had a look and xe2's TCheckListBox *has* a OnClickCheck event.